# Cannot get currentRouteName

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my ApplicationController I have following:

```
init: function () {
    console.log(this.currentRouteName);
}
```

But it logs `undefined` though if I log `console.log(this);` I can see property and its value.

Does someone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I just realized that you're trying to access the property in the `init` function of the controller. That controller is instantiated by the container automatically. When the container creates that object, your application most likely hasn't begun routing yet, so there is no current route.

So I think the short answer is: you can't do that.

---

You need to use `Em.get`. Accessing the property directly works sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't (depending on how the object is structured).

```
console.log(Em.get(this, 'currentRouteName'));
```

or

```
console.log(this.get('currentRouteName'));
```

Comment: I updated my post. I missed something the first time.